# libcurl with C++ on Windows and non-admin user

Tags: c++, windows, libcurl

I am using libcurl (https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) in a Visual C++ project to make http calls to RESTful services. The application when run on Windows using a user which has "admin" rights, works fine. However, when it is executed using a user that has non-admin rights, it crashes.

I am using the following code for initialisation,

```
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);
curl = curl_easy_init();
```

which is where I guess may be failing

The question that I have is, does anybody know if libcurl requires admin rights and permission?

Thanks in advance
Sushil

Comment: Yes, I know that libcurl doesn't need admin rights or permissions.

Comment: Thanks Thomas - will check then why it is crashing.